# ¿Como hacer un chat uno a uno con websocket php y ratched?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

Hola estoy practicando con websockets para hacer un chat basico. Para ello eh instalado ratched hasta el momento eh logrado hacer un chat general es decir donde si envio un mensaje lo reciben todos para ello tengo esto en php

```
 public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }

    }
```

Sin embargo mi objetivo es lograr un chat uno a uno para ello eh llegado hasta esto

```
 public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {


        // Parsea el mensaje como JSON (suponiendo que el mensaje sea un objeto JSON)
        $data = json_decode($msg);
        echo $data->destinatarioId;
        if ($data === null) {
            echo "Error al parsear el mensaje JSON" . PHP_EOL;
            return;
        }
        
 
        if (!isset($data->destinatarioId)) {
            echo "Mensaje sin destinatario: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
            return;
        }
        
        $destinatarioId = $data->destinatarioId;
        
        // Encuentra al destinatario en el registro de destinatarios
        if (!isset($this->destinatarios[$destinatarioId])) {
            echo "Destinatario no encontrado: $destinatarioId" . PHP_EOL;
            return;
        }
        
        $destinatario = $this->destinatarios[$destinatarioId];
        
        // Envía el mensaje solo al destinatario
        $destinatario->send($msg);
        
    }
```

pero siempre obtengo destinatario no encontrado pese que desde js si estoy enviando un id que corresponde a un usuario que hizo login. Este es mi javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
        conn.onopen = function(e) {
            console.log("Connection established!");
        };

        conn.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
            //recibe el mensaje 
            const resp = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log("Usuario:" + resp.idUser + "mensaje:" + resp.message)
            
            //$('#container-msg').append("<p><b> " + resp.nombre + " </b> " + resp.msg + "  </p>");
        };



        $("#btn-submit-msg").click(function(e) {
          var message = quill.root.innerHTML;
          const destinatarioId = $("#idUsuario").val(); 
          const idUser = $("#idUsuario").val();

      
          // Envía el mensaje al servidor a través de WebSocket
          var messageData = {
            type: "message",
            destinatarioId: destinatarioId,
            message: message,
            idUser: idUser,
          };
            //envia el mensaje
            conn.send(JSON.stringify(messageData))

            ///mostrar msg en html

           // $('#container-msg').append("<p><b>Tu: </b> " + msg + "  </p>");

        })
 
});
```

Como se puede ver si estoy enviando und destinatarioId desde un campo oculto en el html pero lo unico que recibo como respuesta del socket es destinario no encontrado:1 cuando se envia de un lado y destinatario no encontrado: 2
cabe decir que 1 corresponde al primer usuario y 2 al segundo usuario entonces en teoria se envia el destinatarioId pero el socket me muestra el mensaje que coloque de destinatario no encontrado que podria estar mal llevo horas y no logro dar con una solucion.

Comment: y ya validaste que se recibe en el websocket? independientemente de la respuesta que de el web socket debe estar llegando algo ... hay es donde tienes que comenzar a depurar... muy seguramente los datos no los estas enviendo del html al websocker y luego al backend ... y muy seguramente no has validado si estan llegando al backend.